# How to keep a View on top of my Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

Sounds like a question that was answered before but from my research I couldn't find a solution. My layout is roughly the following:

[image]

The main area is a container where I'll add/replace Fragments, and the bottom is where I place a bottom navigation menu. The pink View is a button that I need to place on top of my menu (and that's not working).

Every time I add a Fragment to the main view, my "Menu" text disappears, even though the TextView is added after the container View. Same with the pink Button, which is added after the bottom menu container (see my xml below).

How can I keep both "Menu" TextView and the pink Button always on top of my Fragments?

This is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#eee"
    tools:context="com.wecancer.wecancer.activities.Menu">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_container_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="520dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        >
    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main_center_tv"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/main_bottom_menu_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/lightGray"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        >

    </FrameLayout>

    <Button
        android:elevation="1dp"
        android:id="@+id/menu_plus_img"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This`

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/main_bottom_menu_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    >

</FrameLayout>

<Button
    android:elevation="1dp"
    android:id="@+id/menu_plus_img"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop"
    android:layout_marginLeft="71dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="71dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/main_center_tv"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:text="@string/menu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/menu_plus_img"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/menu_plus_img"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/menu_plus_img"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/menu_plus_img" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_container_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="520dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/menu_plus_img">


</FrameLayout>
```

`

Comment: It worked for the TextView but not for the button, but why? Can you include an explanation as to why the TextView would be on top now?

Comment: you used  layout_centerHorizontal="true" in text view that put it in the center of screen and on top of it frame layout which is empty at start but when you load fragment on it it hide the text view below it.
What problem you are facing with the button?

Comment: I'm using this library https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar which apparently adds elements programatically. So I can't bring my Button to the front, even using bringToFront() after the view is built.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change the order of the views in the layout while using a Framelayout

The complexity of your layout does not require a RelativeLayout so you just have to switch.

Comment: Give a practical solution, please. That's not really an answer since I said the order should be correct and you say "just change the order".

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know why methods like [bringToFront](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#bringToFront()), [bringChildToFront](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#bringChildToFront(android.view.View)), or adding and removing View's children to change their indices didn't work. So I actually had to create a new layout structure.

Instead of:

```
RelativeLayout
...FrameLayout
...TextView
...FrameLayout
...Button
```

I did:

```
FrameLayout
...RelativeLayout
......FrameLayout
......FrameLayout
......TextView
...RelativeLayout
......Button
```

Whereas the second RelativeLayout has only a button and a transparent background. My full xml code is below as a reference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_root_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#eee"
        tools:context="com.wecancer.wecancer.activities.Menu">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:id="@+id/main_bottom_menu_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/lightGray"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_container_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/main_center_tv"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/menu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:onClick="menuPlusBt"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/menu_plus_img"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/green_circle"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```